# Numpy parse to ndarray from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have stringified ndarray passed from server to the client-side, the example of that array could be seen below

```
import numpy as np

str_array = "[[0.1233 0.333 4.1111] [0.1233 0.333 4.1111] [0.1233 0.333 4.1111]]"
arr = np.fromstring(str_array, dtype=np.float32, sep = ' ')

print(arr)
```

when I run that code, it would raise an error message:

```
  File "example.py", line 89, in <module>
    arr = np.fromstring(str_array, dtype=np.float32)
ValueError: string size must be a multiple of element size
```

I want my stringified array to become a ndarray again. How can I solve this?

Comment: That stringified ndarray is not designed  for parsing like this.  Don't build this process into your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html#numpy-matrix) and than `reshape`

```py
>>> np.matrix(str_array).reshape(-1,3)
matrix([[0.1233, 0.333 , 4.1111],
        [0.1233, 0.333 , 4.1111],
        [0.1233, 0.333 , 4.1111]])
```

Or to get `ndarray` use attribute [`matrix.A`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.A.html#numpy-matrix-a)

```py
>>> np.matrix(str_array).reshape(-1,3).A
array([[0.1233, 0.333 , 4.1111],
       [0.1233, 0.333 , 4.1111],
       [0.1233, 0.333 , 4.1111]])
```

Comment: I'm not looking to diss a 'competing' answer, but I note that the documentation you link to says "It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the future."

Answer (score 2):

I note that the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.4.x/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) says that `np.fromstring()` "Return a new 1-D array initialized from raw binary or text data in string."

If you know the dimensions of your array, one simple workaround for the fact your data is 2D would simply to be:

```
str_array = str_array.replace("]", "")
str_array = str_array.replace("[", "")
np.fromstring(str_array, sep=' ').reshape(3,3)
```

Which does yield:

```
array([[0.1233, 0.333 , 4.1111],
       [0.1233, 0.333 , 4.1111],
       [0.1233, 0.333 , 4.1111]])
```